# I can´t my Login to MySQL works properly

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFGPu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAuXG.png)I have contructed this 2 files. The REGISTER works properly but the LOGIN seems doesn't find the user 'cause always I receive"echo 2". Any suggestion. Thanks

LOGIN:

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$user = $_POST['User'];
$mail = $_POST['Mail'];
$token = $_POST['Token'];
$pass = $_POST['Pass'];
$query_user = "SELECT * FROM Proteos WHERE User = '$user'";
$query_pass = "SELECT * FROM Proteos WHERE Pass = '$pass'";
$query_execuser = mysql_query($query_user) or die(mysql_error());
$query_execupass = mysql_query($query_pass) or die(mysql_error());
$rowsuser = mysql_num_rows($query_execuser);
$rowspass = mysql_num_rows($query_execpass);
if ($rowuser==0){
    echo 2;
}else if ($rowuser==$rowpass){
    echo 3; 
}else if ($rowuser!=$rowpass) {
echo 4;
}
mysqli_close($con)
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: So many issues. Firstly, you're passing unsanitsed content straight to the database (and doing so using a deprecated method.) Your question also doesn't include anything saying what the value of `$_POST['User']` is - are you certain that it's set, and set right?

Comment: Secondly - you're using two queries, and you don't need to; you can just add an AND to a single query; that will return one row where both username and password match. As it is, you may get a fail if two users have the same password.

Comment: Thirdly - don't store unencrypted passwords in your database.

Comment: My REGISTER file is very similar and works properly but. This one does'nt. Any sugestion to get better that code?

Comment: Well, first thing you should do is make sure your inputs are correct. Check that `$_POST['User']` is being set, and is correct. Then echo out your generated SQL, and see if that looks OK; you can check it by entering it directly in your database.

Comment: I´ll encrypt passwords. Thanks. The two querys are used to validate if the user exist and then validate if in the same row the password match. The message i receive is the user donst exist. I cant undestand

Comment: No. The two queries don't do that. They retrieve a row with the username, and a row with the password. Those are not necessarily the same row - what if we've both got the same password? You're getting a message saying that there are no rows with that username in the database, but again - we've no idea if your SQL is being generated correctly, because we don't know what the form looks like, or if `$_POST['User']` is set.

Comment: ...and no idea what the register stuff looks like neither and what the values in db are.

Comment: *"don't store unencrypted passwords in your database"* - @andrewsi I think you meant for them to hash. OP might get the wrong impression between encryption and hashing ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I'm a tad rusty, clearly; thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: I follwo the comment of andrewsi. And after check the user dont exist it creates again the user. Then the $POST[] has the correct data.

Comment: @BrandonPrieto - could you add the HTML for your form?

Comment: @andrewsi The data came from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

first,correct your query select query, that is use one instead of two

```
e.g $query_user = "SELECT * FROM Proteos WHERE user = '$user' and pass='$pass'"
```

second, make a practice of using lowercase while querying db e.g pass instead of Pass, user instead of User, some servers may not work property on this,
third, call your new form, I cant see it here, as in  I only see echo for values, instead something like `header("location : you_file.php");`

Comment: I think its not about lower case cause my Register file is very similar and it works fine. The data came and goes to android that why you cant see any form

Comment: Solved. I think that was about deprecated commands. I used the new ones and it worked